# Make this Replacewith on .each function jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple code like this:

```
$('#tblPrice').replaceWith( $('#tblPrice').html()
   .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='table'")
   .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div")
   .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
   .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
   .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
   .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
   );
```

I have multiple tables that has an id of `tblPrice`. it replaces only one table at a time
so how to make this an `.each function ()`

Comment: You should only have 1 instance of an ID on your page.  Change it to a class first of all, and then use `$(".className").each(function() { });`

Comment: make that id as class. and then use each..

Comment: the html is an output of other web so it is processed already with that id. how am i supposed to change the id to class?

Comment: so how can i be able to change the id attribute to classname then?

Comment: If they're the only tables on the page then you can simply refer to them as `$("table")`

Comment: can i use an attribute selector like `$('table[id="tblPrice"]')`??

Answer (score 1):

> I have multiple tables that has an id of `tblPrice`.

This is your problem. [**IDs must be unique**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#the-id-attribute). JavaScript will stop looking past the first matching ID it finds. Modify your `#tblPrice` tables to all have different IDs but give each a similar class, then use the class selector instead of the ID selector.

For instance:

```
<table class="tblPrice" id="tblPrice1">
    ...
</table>
<table class="tblPrice" id="tblPrice2">
    ...
</table>
```

To turn this into an `.each()` loop, you can then simply:

```
$('.tblPrice').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.replaceWith($this.html() ... );
});
```

You'll also want to change that `id="table"` in your HTML replacement for the same reason above. Use a class instead:

```
.replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div class='table'")
```

Comment: adding class would help then.. $('#tblPrice').addClass('pricelist')
is this correct?

Comment: @Onimax no you'll need to manually change your HTML. You cannot have two elements on the same page with the same ID. It's invalid.

Comment: @Onimax No - add the class in your markup and remove duplicate IDs.  This needs to be done before the page is served to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

just take a class attribute in all the tables and put the below code:-

```
$('.tblPrice').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.replaceWith($this.html() ... );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**IDs** are supposed to be unique in the DOM. Even if you use the `.each` method here, you will always get the first element only every time with the ID.

I will suggest to use class instead and add them to all the tables like `myTable` and modify your code like:

```
$('.myTable').replaceWith(function () {
    return $(this).html()
        .replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='table'")
        .replace(/<tr/gi, "<div")
        .replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
        .replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
        .replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
        .replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as the comments said..

```
$(".tblPrice").each(function() { 
$(this).replaceWith( $(this).html()
.replace(/<tbody/gi, "<div id='table'")
.replace(/<tr/gi, "<div")
.replace(/<\/tr>/gi, "</div>")
.replace(/<td/gi, "<span")
.replace(/<\/td>/gi, "</span>")
.replace(/<\/tbody/gi, "<\/div")
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing with jquery you can change the styling of the table and it's children element to behave like div's and span's.

For example,

```
table, tr, tbody{
    display: block;  /* div */
    /* other css styles */
}

td{
    display: inline; /* span */
    /* other css styles */
}
```

This ofcourse doesnot completely change the table elements but it might help you in what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: actually im using this code on something like counting cells by `TD` for correction purposes. im changing those table element residing on the `TD` so it won't be counted.

Comment: @Onimax then you can just add a new class using jquery to those elements. This class will do the same as I suggested above in my post.

Comment: how can I add another class through it? can you just give me atleast a brief example on how to add classname through this ID attribute